# How to use Tinymce in Angular 2 after it's stable release

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce, rich-text-editor

1. [angular2 wysiwyg tinymce implementation and 2-way-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841335/angular2-wysiwyg-tinymce-implementation-and-2-way-binding)
2. [Initialize 3rd party library in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907807/initialize-3rd-party-library-in-angular-2)

I've been trying out several solutions given in **stackoverflow** answers. But, my **tinymce** editor is not getting loaded. Just want to make sure is there any specific ways after the stable release of Angular 2?
Since the directives are not available in the object parsed in the @Component(), i can't use the solution given in the link 1. Link 2 doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be exist when I was posting the question it seems. Later on, Following as mentioned in the [Link](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/) helped.

And, also follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522036/tinymce-not-working-in-angular-cli-project/41663740#41663740) along with the question if you find any difficulties.

This solution should work in the stable angular versions (I've done with it up to 2.3.1 from the stable release)