# How to make angular2 component ng-invalid

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I need to write a component that can be used in a form. I want to publish it as ng-invalid for the form.

that is my form template/view:

```
    <form  #myForm="ngForm">        
    <domain-base-value  [(ngModel)]="value.value" name="bla" #bla="ngModel">
    </domain-base-value>
    <div [hidden]="myForm.valid || myForm.pristine">
      Form is not valid
    </div>
    </form>
```

that is domain-base-value component view:

`<input [(ngModel)]="value" required />`

if I run it, the input get ng-invalid but not the domain-base-value and the form.
I can move the `required` to the form, but I want that the child component will have the logic when is it valid and when not.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your sub-component ngModel-compatible by making it implementing a custom value accessor. This way you will be able to use `ngModel` and directives like `ngFormControl` to apply validators.

Here is a sample:

```
const MY_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent), multi: true});

@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ MY_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class MyInputComponent extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    if (value!=null) {
      super.writeValue(value.toString());
    }
  }

  // call when your internal input is updated
  doOnChange(val) {
    this.onChange(val);
  }
}
```

For more details, see this article (section "NgModel-compatible component"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

See also this question:

- [angular2 wysiwyg tinymce implementation and 2-way-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841335/angular2-wysiwyg-tinymce-implementation-and-2-way-binding/36841485#36841485)

Comment: I'm already bound to ngModel. But I'm asking on validation. You didn't show how to make the child component not valid. I mean to get ng-invalid class.

Answer (score 0):

Use disabled to accomplish this

```
<form  #myForm="ngForm">
    <domain-base-value  [(ngModel)]="value.value" name="bla" #bla="ngModel">
    </domain-base-value>
    <div [disabled]="!form.valid || form.pristine">
      Form is not valid
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

To repeat:

- You have got a component, which holds an input field.
- This input field itself is a ngModel and has the attributes ng-invalid
- Your form, which calls the component does not know about the invalid input field in the `domain-base-value` component

I think the problem is, that your ngForm does not know about the input field inside your component. My solution would be to add the ngForm as @Input parameter to the `domain-base-value` component and inside your component add the ngModel to the form. Your form would look like:

```
<form  #myForm="ngForm">
    <domain-base-value  
        [(ngModel)]="value.value" 
        name="bla" 
        #bla="ngModel"
        [form]="myForm"
    >
    </domain-base-value>
    <div [hidden]="myForm.valid || myForm.pristine">
        Form is not valid
    </div>
 </form>
```

Inside your component it would look like:

```
@Component({...})
export class DomainBaseValue implements OnInit {

    @Input() form: NgForm;

    @ViewChild('input1') input1;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form.addControl(this.input1);
    }

}
```

This should append the NgModel to your NgForm and you should now see the correct attributes on your form.

Hope this helps.