# Is it possible to perform a two way binding on a custom directive with ngModel?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

My use case is completely different. When I strip off all the other factors, it boils down to this.

Say I have the following input element

```
<input type="text" [customDirective] [(ngModel)]="myValue" >
```

The job of this `customDirective` is to look into value entered by the user and changed its value based on the input on the fly.

How to achieve two-way binding for this.

I played around with ControlValueAccessor, DefaultValueAccessor. But no matter what I do, I was not able to achieve the two-way binding. The maximum I achieved at one time is view update on model update but not the other way round. But that code is somewhere lost.

Here is the vanilla [plunker link.](https://plnkr.co/edit/k32t8l?p=preview)

PS: I already referred the following. But none of them were helpful in achieving 2-way binding w.r.t to directive

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

[angular2 wysiwyg tinymce implementation and 2-way-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841335/angular2-wysiwyg-tinymce-implementation-and-2-way-binding)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do the same by using Pipe for it

Comment: @ranakrunal9 how pipe would change the value of `ngModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this.

Model to UI changes can be done using `ControlValueAcessor`

UI to Model can be done like below

```
import {Output} from '@angular/core';
```

Use the event emitter

```
@Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();
```

Whenever data gets changed emit the event

```
this.ngModelChange.emit(YOUR_NEW_VALUE);
```

Here is the detailed example

[Using Tinymce editor as a directive](https://github.com/Abhijith-Nagaraja/tinymce-docs/blob/master/integrations/angular2.md#sample-directive-implementation-with-ngmodel-two-way-binding)